# How to add JPG to Xcode Asset Catalog

Tags: xcode, png, jpeg, asset-catalog

How do I add JPG images to Images.xcassets?

Selecting Import... only allows me to select PNG, not JPG, files.

Is there a setting to allow an asset catalog to include JPG images?